# Having trouble responding to selections when using a UITableView and swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a question about responding to selections with a UITableView. I want to create a FAQ and trigger an action when the user selects a row. I'm just testing it right now, and set it to print a log message when the user selects one of the rows on the table view. However, in the simulator nothing happens.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help enlighten me?

Thanks in advance. Below is my code.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { 

let iEdCafeVid = [
    ("temp", "temp"),
    ("temp", "temp"),
    ("temp", "temp") ]

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return iEdCafeVid.count //the number of spots in the array
}

//uses the numberOfRowsInSection method
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell //because creating as AnyObject.
    //var cell = UITableViewCell() //instantiating class, but should use the dequeue option.

    //need to add the prototype cell in the storyboard before the dequeue option will work.

    //creating touple (desciptions of the cell content parts)
    let (videoTitle, subtitle) = iEdCafeVid[indexPath.row] //index parth is the value (i.e. the array in this case) that we created in the numberOfRowsInSection method.

    cell.textLabel.text = videoTitle
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = subtitle

    //retrieve image
    var cellImage = UIImage(named: "CellIcon")
    cell.imageView.image = cellImage

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("user has selected a cell")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Did you set this controller as the delegate of the table view?

Comment: Hi rdelmar, thanks for posting. On storyboard I assigned this class as the delegate and the data source (connection tab). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. It's hard to see what else the problem might be. So to be clear, you do not see the log of "user has selected a cell" when you touch a cell? Does the cell highlight?

Comment: Yes the cell highlights. There are no log reports.

Comment: Hmmm... that's odd. Just to be sure, put this line in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, and see what is gives you: println(tableView.delegate)

Comment: It reads the following three times: Optional(<iEd_FAQ.FirstViewController: 0x7fcec1532410>)

Comment: I copied your code, and it worked fine for me. Is FirstViewController your only view controller?

Comment: Hi, no it's part of a tab bar controller. This is just the first of 5

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped. There's nothing wrong with the code you posted. The fact that the cell highlights means that the touch was received, so I can't see any reason your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is not working. Did you copy and paste (rather than type) the code you show in your question?

Comment: Hi rdelmar, I tried putting it in a single view controller in a new project like you did. I was able to get the report to fire. It's very strange. Maybe it's to do with the tab bar controller? I copied the code onto the post as well.

Comment: Actually there were two minor errors in your code; both textLabel and imageView should have a "?" or "!" after them or your code won't compile, so I don't see how this could be your actual code. The fact that your view controller is embedded in a tab bar controller shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Hi rdelmar, so I added a switch statement to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath I'm getting the logs to fire. Not sure why that would make a difference. I've changed the code to your suggestions. Thanks for all the help